# How to uncheck all child nodes but parent node is still checked and vice versa?

Tags: antd

I'm using AntD V5, currently I have a Tree like this [Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49VSr.png)
I want its behavior to be:

1. When I click the parent node, all its child nodes are checked (this is working)
2. When I uncheck all checked child nodes, their parent node is still checked.
3. When nothing is checked, when I check all child nodes of a parent node, that node is not checked.

Current only the number 1 work.

I tried this but it only unlinks the parent node to all its child nodes

```
checkStrictly={true}
```

This is a working example of Antd Tree [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-tree-antd-5-4-2-forked-ujifp3?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Could you please add your snippet as well or share working examples Stackblitz, codesandbox so we can help you in detail? your above information is not enough to answer the question.

Comment: @AmitRajbhandari I have added a working demo for Antd Tree. Please check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it worked! Below is my onCheck function to pass into Antd Tree

```
const onCheck = (e, info) => {
  const checkedChildrenKeys: (string | number)[] = [];
  const unCheckedChildrenKeys: (string | number)[] = [];
  const checkedCallback = (e: DataNode) => {
    checkedChildrenKeys.push(e.key);
    e.children && e.children.forEach(checkedCallback);
  };
  const uncheckedCallback = (e: DataNode) => {
    unCheckedChildrenKeys.push(e.key);
    e.children && e.children.forEach(uncheckedCallback);
  };
  if (info.checked) {
    if (!info.node.children) {
      setCheckedKeys([...e.checked]);
      return;
    }
    info.node.children.forEach(checkedCallback);
    setCheckedKeys([...e.checked, ...checkedChildrenKeys]);
  } else {
    info.node.children?.forEach(uncheckedCallback);
    const uncheckedList = e.checked.filter(
      (key: any) => !unCheckedChildrenKeys?.includes(key)
    );
    setCheckedKeys(uncheckedList);
  }
};
```

I have updated my codesandbox to demonstrate it. Thanks!